# How to urldecode unicode in php

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, utf-8, urldecode

I have troubles to encode received unicode text via an API in php. The unicode text is received via HTTP GET.

Example: the API sends the unicoded text "Hallo  test" as
%00H%00a%00l%00l%00o%00+%D8%3D%DCM%00+%00t%00e%00s%00t%00+%D8%3D%DCM%D8%3C%DF%FD

In PHP this is received as: " H a l l o   Ø=ÜM   t e s t"

The $_GET variable is in php decoded with urldecode to UTF-8.

How can i get the entended text from this API?

Comment: It's UTF-16 (big endian).

Comment: indeed, thanks. and rawurldecode needed to convert %00. so this works: iconv('utf-16be', 'utf-8', rawurldecode($getvariable))